# Minimum value based off another value - JSON schema

Tags: jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I'm wanting to set a minimum amount on one field based off another field.

For example if I have a `quoteAmountLower` and `quoteAmountUpper` - I want `quoteAmountUpper` to be greater than `quoteAmountLower`.

If lower is 50 then upper has to be more than 50.

```js
properties: {
  quotedAmountLower: {
    type: 'integer',
    minimum: 0
  },
  quotedAmountUpper: {
    type: 'integer',
    // more than quotedAmountLower
    minimum: 0
  }
}
```

Cheers

I've tried using a reference or $id on the `quotedAmountLower`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no keyword in the standard JSON Schema specification that can reference a value in an instance.

There are proposals, for instance https://docs.json-everything.net/schema/vocabs/data-2023/ (related: https://github.com/json-schema-org/json-schema-spec/issues/51) so you will probably either need to customize the JSON Schema library you are using or check if it supports something similar.