# Validate property value based on the value of another property in JSON schema

Tags: json, jsonschema

I'm trying to define a JSON schema that includes validation logic that could validate a property based on the value of another property.

```json
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "A": {"type": "string"},
        "B": {"type": "string"},
        "C": {"type": "string"}
    }
}
```

If the value of `A` is "apple", then the value of `B` and `C` must not be "apple". Essentially, the value of a property must be unique across all properties of the same object.

I understand that I can use `if/then/else` to validate the mutual exclusiveness of values:

```json
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "A": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "B": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "C": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "if": {
    "required": [
      "A"
    ],
    "properties": {
      "A": {
        "const": "apple"
      }
    }
  },
  "then": {
    "required": [
      "B",
      "C"
    ],
    "properties": {
      "B": {
        "not": {
          "const": "apple"
        }
      },
      "C": {
        "not": {
          "const": "apple"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, the problem is the possible value of `A` will not be known upfront. In my use case, users are allowed to enter whatever value they will.

I appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: I don't think conditional validation is possible with dynamic values.  You're not able to provide validate the condition without knowing what that condition is.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Minimum value based off another value - JSON schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78114435/minimum-value-based-off-another-value-json-schema)

Comment: After a bunch of reading, the answer I'm looking for is actually the `$data` keyword, but the proposal was rejected. However, I found that [AJV](https://ajv.js.org/guide/combining-schemas.html#data-reference) does have the keyword implemented as an optional feature.